# ios - Как организовать синхронное выполнение функций с подгрузкой данных через VK API на Swift3

Tags: ios, многопоточность, swift, vkontakte-api, swift3

Доброго дня! Есть 2 функции с запросами к VK, где один запрос использует данные другого: (runGroupSearch() и runGroupByID()).
Проблема в том, что не получается организовать работу так, чтобы второй запрос начал свое выполнение только после того, как первый завершит свое выполнение и будут получены данные. Хочу сделать параллельную async основному потоку очередь, уже в которой задачи выполняются синхронно.

Предполагаю, что здесь понадобится GCD. Пробовал в Playground играться с потоками sync и async разного качества. Там все отлично, здесь беда.
Если completionHandler(), то не знаю, как его использовать.

### viewDidLoad()

```
let userQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated)
let utilityQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    userQueue.async {
        self.userQueue.sync {
            self.testQueue()
        }
        self.userQueue.sync {
            self.runGroupSearch()
        }
        self.userQueue.sync {
            self.testQueue2()
        }
        self.utilityQueue.sync {
            self.runGroupByID()
        }
        self.utilityQueue.sync {
            self.quickSort(eventsArr: self.eventsArr)
        }
        self.utilityQueue.sync {
            self.CatalogTable!.reloadData()
        }
    }
    
}
```

Функции testQueue печатают число 5 раз. Их использую, чтобы в логе увидеть, что вообще происходит. И как по мне, видно, что функции все равно выполняются асинхронно (2 функции testQueue могут выполниться одновременно, а могут, как на логе ниже. Всегда по разному.)

[image: Лог выполнения]

Для самих запросов использую библиотеку SwiftyVK.

Ниже код функций с запросами (они объявлены в том классе, в котором вызываются):

```
var ABC = ["в","с","до"]

func runGroupSearch() {
    
    for i in 0..<ABC.count {
        let letter: String = ABC[i]
        VK.API.Groups.search([VK.Arg.q: "\(letter)", VK.Arg.type: "event", VK.Arg.cityId: "96", VK.Arg.future: "1", VK.Arg.count: "50"]).send(
            onSuccess: {
                response in print("SwiftyVK: Groups.search success \n \(response)")
                
                for j in 0..<response.count {
                    let gid = response[j,"gid"].stringValue
                    let name = response[j,"name"].stringValue
                    let img = response[j,"photo_big"].stringValue
                    if gid != "" && gid != " " {
                        self.groupID.append(gid)
                        self.groupName.append(name)
                        self.groupImage.append(img)
                        
                        // убираем дубли
                        self.groupID = Array(Set(self.groupID))
                        self.groupName = Array(Set(self.groupName))
                        self.groupImage = Array(Set(self.groupImage))
                    }
                }
                self.gIds = self.groupID.joined(separator: ",")
                print("gIds is:\(self.gIds)")
            },
            onError: {
                error in print("SwiftyVK: Groups.search fail \n \(error)")
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Код второй функции запросом, вызов которой хочу осуществить только после выполнения первой (данные для 2-го запросы в self.gIds):

```
func runGroupByID() {
    
    print("gIds is:\(self.gIds)")

    VK.API.Groups.getById([VK.Arg.groupIds:"\(self.gIds)", VK.Arg.fields:"activity,members_count,start_date"]).send(
        onSuccess: {
            response in print("SwiftyVK: Groups.getById success \n \(response)")
            
            for i in 0..<response.count {
                if response[i,"is_closed"] == 0 {
                    let memb = response[i,"members_count"].stringValue
                    let dateStart = response[i,"start_date"].intValue
                    let activity = response[i,"activity"].stringValue
                    
                    self.groupMembers_count.append(memb)
                    self.groupStart_date.append(dateStart)
                    self.groupActivity.append(activity)
                    
                } else {
                    self.groupMembers_count.append("no")
                    self.groupActivity.append("no")
                }
            }
            print("StartDate: \n \(self.groupStart_date)")
        },
        onError: {
            error in print("SwiftyVK: Groups.getById fail \n \(error)")
        }
    )

}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, очень нужна помощь.

### Платформа iOS 10.*, Swift 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну так если Вы хотите по окончании первой вызвать вторую, просто вставьте вторую в конец блока `onSuccess` первой:

```
    }
    self.gIds = self.groupID.joined(separator: ",")
    print("gIds is:\(self.gIds)")

    self.runGroupByID()
},
```

Здесь Вы ничего не добьетесь используя sync, т.к. в своем потоке Вы синхронно запускаете асинхронный VK.API.Groups.search..., дальше он выполняет что должен, а Ваш поток приступает к следующей задаче.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Проблема в том, что первый запрос я выполняю в цикле (на каждой итерации подставляю элемент массива ABC с поисковыми словами) и накапливая данные, формирую строку self.gIds. Эту строку мне нужно подставить во 2-ой запрос (он выполняется один раз). Так как ограничение VK API составляет 3 запроса в секунду, то у меня не получится в цикле выполнять сразу 2 запроса (будет возвращена ошибка). Нет ли у меня шанса сделать из async запроса синхронный?

Comment: @IliaFedorov недосмотрел цикл. Если так делать, то Вам необходимо будет ждать выполнения всех "первых" запросов перед выполнением второго, плюс могут возникнуть проблемы с переменными, т.к. их дергают разные потоки. Может лучше переделать на цепочку запросов? Выполнился первый search - пошел второй search,  закончились search - вызвался getById.

Comment: А знаете, вы мне на самом деле очень сильно помогли. Действительно, так и сделал, встроил второй запрос (функцию self.runGroupByID()) в success блок первого, с одним маленьким условием: 
`if self.ABC[i] == "до" { self.runGroupByID() }`. 
Т.е. пробегаюсь по массиву ABC (поисковые слова) и т.к. он задается вручную и я знаю, какой элемент в этом массиве последний, то для него условие и сделал (после выполнения кода success блока)...Как только до него цикл дошел, то только тогда запускаю след. запрос. Еще раз спасибо!